# Twilio TaskRouter not working

Tags: twilio

I am working on Contact Center application using Twilio TaskRouter and Nodejs.
I have setup all the TaskRouter configuration by following quick start tutorial but when I call to Twilio Contact Center number (Twilio Number) every time call get canceled and shows Reason for cancelation as **Max assignment exceeded** below is code.

```
app.post('/call', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Incoming Call Center!!');
    var twiml = new Twilio.TwimlResponse();
    var message = "Thanks for calling support line. One of our agents will speak with you soon.";
    var json = JSON.stringify({selected_type:"support"});
    twiml.say(message, {
          voice:'woman',
          language:'en-gb'
    });
    twiml.enqueue({workflowSid:sid}, function(node) {
        node.task(json);
    });
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/xml'
    });
    res.end(twiml.toString());
    console.log('Outbound : ',twiml.toString());
}); 
app.post('/assign', function(req, res) {
    var reservationSid = JSON.stringify(req.body.ReservationSid);
    var taskSid = JSON.stringify(req.body.TaskSid);
    console.log('Reservation SID : ', reservationSid);
    console.log('Task SID : ', taskSid);

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "instruction": "dequeue",
        "from": fromNo
    });

    // dequeue a reservation

    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    });
    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(data);
});
```

when I use **instruction** as **accept** then Task Assignment Status shows assigned and Worker also shows Busy but no call initiated to the worker contact_uri.

I am using Twilio Trial account. 
Is am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio employee here.

First of all, sorry for the delay in response on both of these posts. help@twilio.com is the quickest way to get in touch with us.

Everything above looks good other than potentially the **fromNo**. We've corrected our docs recently to denote that this isn't a required field. Can you try removing this?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#dequeue-call

Comment: Thank you, it is working fine now, i have removed **fromNo** and it is working fine.